# Лучше удалить запись в базе или поставить ей отметку?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица вида

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| message_id | compete_type | completed |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Когда создается запись, то ей присваивается какой-то тип `compete_type` (например 3), значение `completed` равно нулю.

Когда создается еще одна запись, где `compete_type = 3`, то уже существующим записям с `compete_type = 3` присваивается `completed = 1`

И так бесконечно.

Причем из этой таблицы выбираются значения только с `completed = 0`.

Что же лучше, присваивать `completed = 1` и выбирать только `completed = 0`, либо вместо присвоения удалять старые записи?

Comment: Надо определиться нужны ли Вам старые записи? Если нет то лучше удалять. Но для большей оптимизации можно удалять не по 1 записи а пачками, по событию или времени. Например: DELETE FROM myTable WHERE completed = 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Настойчиво рекомендую попрофилировать и понять, что для Вас лучше, но современные базы данных давно научились сами помечать удаленные записи. В результате делаете дармовую работу.

- база данных умеет использовать удаленные записи, что бы вставлять туда новые (это кстати обясняет тот факт, что "Select не гарантирует порядка записей, с которым они вставлялись". Но некоторые базы все же нуждаются в регулярном vacuum.
- если используется индекс, то он также будет увеличиваться, если старые записи не удалять. Как следствие, все будет медленее, если старые записи не удалять.
- если записей будет вставлятся и удалятся много (удалятся меткой "запись удалена" - `completed = 1`), то база будет распухать, и придется для каждой таблицы делать ручками удаление и разбираться, какие записи нужно удалять. То есть, усложняем работу сисадминам.

Но если это домашний проект-велосипед, то можно все что угодно.

Comment: Допустим, что записей будет очень много добавляться и удаляться, что за удаление тогда придется делать?

Comment: имеется ввиду "удаление в стиле автора".

Comment: понятно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Ну если записи с `completed = 1` никогда не достаются и вам они не нужны, то зачем им храниться в базе. В таком случае их лучше удалять, с точки зрения экономии памяти.

Comment: Экономия памяти таким образом получается не всегда